# How do we get visual representation of core data in Xcode 14?

Tags: ios, ide, xcode14

There used to be editor style button which is completely missing in Xcode Version 14.0 (14A309), earlier it was broken but at least after few try it use to work.

Comment: I’ve been working on a replacement CoreData graph viewer - if you'd be interested in being a beta tester, please let me know. Email address is in my profile https://stackoverflow.com/users/123632/ashley-mills?tab=profile

Answer (score 8):

It looks like this feature has been removed
["We fixed the problem of: The diagram view has been removed from the Core Data data model editor in Xcode 14."](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/710008)

Comment: So sad... loved that..